# Understanding Epictetus' burning down of the Capitol

Tags: ambiguity, books

Excerpt from Epictetus' Discourses, Book I, Chapter 8 (emphasis mine):

> You know, I once said the same thing to Musonius when he reproached me for not discovering the omission in a certain syllogism. **I said, 'It's not like I burned down the Capitol.' And he said, 'Idiot, the omission here is the Capitol.'**
>
> I mean, are these the only crimes, killing your father and burning down the Capitol? But to use one's impressions recklessly, carelessly and at random, to fail to analyse an argument as either valid proof or fallacy, and, in a word, to  fail to see in the act of question and answer what agrees with your position and what conflicts - is nothing wrong in all of that?

I suppose that Capitol is the name of some ancient city, but I nonetheless struggle to understand Epictetus' message here.

Is it:

1. A simile? Not observing that a premise is missing from a syllogism is as grave as burning down a city?
2. A literal correlation? That omission from the syllogism was about the Capitol?
3. If something else, what?

**Update**: as per @Cascabel's comment, Capitol is a building part of the [The Capitoline Hill](http://www.museicapitolini.org/en/sede/campidoglio_antico) in Ancient Rome.

Comment: When Epictetus referred to the Capitol, he meant [this](http://www.museicapitolini.org/en/sede/campidoglio_antico). The point seems to be that what he missed in the syllogism was more substantial than burning down  the building.

Comment: This seems to be a copy/paste of [the reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stoicism/comments/k4nwdv/understanding_epictetus_burning_down_of_the/).

Comment: @Cascabel yes, I posted the question on Reddit too.

Comment: Well, now we are going in circles, because the "self-answer" posted below quotes a comment from   that post on reddit, which was inadequate there.

Comment: The first metaphor involved, that negated by Epictetus, is 'burning down the Capitol' ≅ 'Missing the omission in syllogism A'. (I can't find a 'does not represent' symbol, to show a 'rejected-metaphor'.) Musonius tweaked the metaphor to 'The Capitol itself' ≅ 'The omission in syllogism A' (and perhaps sloppy analysis per se). The Capitol (think those great buildings in the US) is a further figurative representation, of an enormity.

Answer (score -1):

As per Reddit user @Kromulent's [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stoicism/comments/k4nwdv/understanding_epictetus_burning_down_of_the/), saying that "it's not like I burned down the Capitol" is an ancient version of our modern "it's not the end of the world".

So it is a simile.

And the meaning of his teacher's reply is that he actually made a major error even if it's not the worst that can be made.

Comment: I updated the answer with more details.